# filling routing table with next hop addresses

Tags: routing, internet, networking

in a multi hop network when the packet leaves the source is it loaded with all the ips of the stops on its journey, then at each hop it checks the bitmask with the nodes routing table to see if this is node is one of the destinations on the path? if not how are the routing tables of nodes being filled properly?

Comment: I am assuming the nodes don't have a default route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when the packet leaves the source is it loaded with all the ips of the stops on its journey

No. Each hop/gateway has its own routing table and forward based on that and the packet's destination address.

> how are the routing tables of nodes being filled properly?

In the simplest case, a router with a single uplink just uses a default route/gateway. Locally connected networks are automatically populated to the routing table.

Remote networks that use a different gateway than the default one require the admin to either set up a static routing entry for each network or set up a routing protocol that enables the router to exchange routes with its peers on its own.

Comment: so would you consider routing tables to be constant? aside from for example a single up-link router like you described is either populating itself or depopulating itself every so often

Comment: Routing tables are constant when the network isn't changing, and they (should) change when the network does. A simple router has one port connected to a local network and another port to "everywhere else". The routing table has those two entries.